# Proper CMS for event-driven sites

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, content-management-system

I'm going to convert a custom-coded website to one of the most known CMS.
The site is a cultural events-driven (concerts, shows, etc.)

The "objects" we need to port for each event are:

```
- custom gallery
- hierarchical tags (starting with place, theme, etc.)
- complex event dates (not just since-to, but many custom ranges)
- search engine that considers all the above
```

I have experience to easily build sites with Wordpress, but we have noticed ( thanks to feedback from our customers) that when the sites gets bigger than the usual 10 pages and with many images, the management gets very confused, it is almost impossible to find and reuse an image added months before, and so on.
Also, finding a ready-made plugin is really daunting, in the past I've never found a plugin able to do exactly what I needed, either because the requirements were too specific, other times it was plagued with unfixable bugs.

Being this a 10 years site, there are thousands of events and images.

**My question**

I know that Wordpress is not exactly a CMS, it is more a Blog with CMS features, so I'm  thinking to switch to a proper CMS.

The first names are Joomla and Drupal, but I wonder winch one is best suited on the front-end (to mimic the original site features) and on the back-end (a proper galley manager, good wysiwyg editor, tags/cateries manager, and **easiness for the editor** )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use drupal with some modules for creating this site.

For events you will need [Date module](http://drupal.org/project/date)

Tags are supported in drupal by default taxonomy module also you can create nested tags over there and there are many module to handle tags eg [taxonomy manager](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager)

Using cck module with date module you can create many date for events (For drupal 7 there is no need of cck module)

And for [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) , and for image gallerias an for SEO many modules are present in drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I specialize in event-driven websites, and use Drupal exclusively.  I highly recommend it for your needs.  But then I don't know very much about Joomla :-) ...

Drupal has a great development community, and an abundance of good useful contributed modules available.